# Switching between different layouts in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I have a menu that has 2 selections that have the onclick feature used in the xml with the methods convertC and convertF.

I have 2 layouts in my application: CelsiusConversion and Fahrenheit Conversion.

What i am wondering is how do i set up the methods to use the layout i want.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: See this http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do this:

1. Create new Activities fir each layout.  Then you would do this to start the one selected"

   ```
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), convertFActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
   ```
2. Create new Dialogs for each.

   ```
   FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
   ExportXMLDialog dialog = new convertFDialog();
   dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
   dialog.show(fm, 0;;
   ```
3. Put both layouts in the layout you are displaying or want to display.  Then you can toggle their visibility by setting one to VISIBLE and the other to GONE.